# Enable MsSQL PDO driver on LAMP w/ PHP5.3.6

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, apache, pdo

I've been googling and searching SO for the better part of an hour, and fail to find a good answer. I'm a server admin noob here, so I'm sure this is not too difficult, but I sure don't know what to do.

Info: 
Running PHP5.3.6 on an Apache server, using WHM/cPanel as the server admin GUI

I'm trying to connect to a client's MsSQL database, and alas, get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()
```

So I start googling, see that perhaps that's not the best function to use anyway. Alright, so I look at PHPinfo for PDO support:

```
PDO drivers     sqlite, sqlite2, mysql
```

How on earth do I get mssql to show up in that list, so I can do something like the following:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mssql:host=host.name;dbname=name", 'user', 'pass');
```

I can't seem to google my way out of this one. Any thoughts?

Comment: Certainly welcome to try here but perhaps this question would be better placed on serverfault.com?  I've voted to migrate it.

Comment: I have to admit I didn't even realize there was a serverfault.com, migrating it is fine with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can uncomment the "extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll" line in php.ini if you have access to it.

If it still doesn't work, you might want to try this (once again, only if you have access to it):

> ntwdblib.dll - The most common issue is that you do not have the
>   ntwdblib.dll file installed in your PHP directory (where php.exe is,
>   or sometimes placing it in the ext directory works as well). This
>   library can be found with your Enterprise Manager dll's or in your SQL
>   servers system32 folder. It's generally best to take the file from the
>   server where SQL Server is installed -quoted from
>   http://www.helpspot.com/helpdesk/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=13

If you are doing this on some kind of rented hosting (IE: Shared Hosting) you may need to contact the support from the hosting provider to get them to enable it if you can't get it to work.

http://us.php.net/mssql also has a lot of information. The installation is what I just stated above, but the user comments address a lot of more unique situations and provide more detail.

Comment: Did the two things you suggested but I had to end up contacting Storm's support team. We'll see what they say.

Comment: When you run phpinfo() do you see ANY PDO drivers? If PDO is not enabled on your server it is definitely something the provider will have to do for you.

Comment: sqlite, sqlite2, mysql. I edited the .ini file to add the correct type and tried installing it but to no avail. My host support guy ended up installing '--with-mssql=/usr/local/freetds' and it seems to be working now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though.

Comment: yeah, they must not have had it installed at all, it's a shame when hosting providers ignore such common and powerful tools. I'm glad you got it resolved.